# How to create vector of binary values based on correspondence between two other vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, given two vectors `A` *(N by 1)* and `B` *(Q by 1, where Q < N)*, where A contains a large number of `N` coefficients, and `B` contains a small subset of Q of these coefficients; how can I compute a binary vector *(N by 1)* which uses zeros and ones to indicate whether a coefficient of `A` is also in `B` or not?

Comment: Look into [`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).

Comment: I would like to use the vector as a binary variable in a regression model. I believe `ismember` returns a logical vector, not zeros and ones, right?

Comment: Then, just convert to double with `double()`?

Comment: Alright this admittedly turned out to be more simple than I thought. Shall we make this a short answer or is it too simple of a question?

Comment: @Divakar: I suggest turning this into an answer.

Comment: @Constantin It's most probably a duplicate and considering the *great* search engine we have here on SO, I would suggest deleting it. Or if someone else could find any such duplicate, would be nice.